# Existence of a point where $f''$ changes sign

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

> Suppose $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ and three times differentiable on $(a,b)$, with $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, $f'(a+) = f'(b-) > 0$, and $f'''(x) > 0$ for $x \in (a,b)$ (NB: $a\mathord{+}$ means approach $a$ from the right/above, $b\mathord{-}$ means approach $b$ from left/below).
>
> Show there is a point $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f''(x)<0$ for $x \in [a,c)$ and $f''(x)>0$ for $x \in (c,b]$.

Here is my thinking (and I realize it's not a lot! – is this along the right lines?):
Use Rolle's Theorem on $f$ to show there exists a $c$ in $(a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$. Since we have that $f'(a+) = f'(b-) > 0$, it must be that at the point $c$ we have this change in sign of $f''$.

Sorry what I've got is not too thorough... I just need some direction in terms of formalizing this line of argument.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for how to format math on this site.

Answer (score 0):

$f'''(x)>0$ implies that there is at most one sign change of $f''$ in the interval [a,b].

With Rolle's theorem and the fact $f'(a+)>0\ ,\ f'(b-)>0$ the possibility of no
sign changes can be ruled out because the first derivate must decrease at some point
and increase at some point.

Comment: So we've established that f'' changes sign exactly once, but how do we show that this sign change occurs at c?

Comment: $c$ is simply the value for which $f''(c)=0$. At this point, the sign changes.